# Blending mode for individual letters within a word in CSS

Tags: html, css, blending, color-blending

I wonder if it is possible to apply a blending mode to individual letters to see how they overlap with negative letter spacing. As I understand it sees whole text string as one object and doesn't apply blending for glyphs within it. Maybe there is a clever way to do this effect without dividing text to individual one letter strings?

Thanks[image: This is how I want it to look]

Tried applying 'mix-blend-mode: multiply' and 'background-blend-mode: multiply' to the class but individual letters still don't overlap...

Comment: To start each letter would need to be in an individual element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you need some help from JS to achieve your goal exactly.
Please check this

```js
const element = document.getElementsByClassName("blend");
let text = element[0].getAttribute("data");
let blendMode = element[0].getAttribute("blend-mode");
for(let chr of text) 
  element[0].innerHTML += "<span style='mix-blend-mode: "+blendMode+"' >"+chr+"</span>";
```

```css
.blend-style {
  letter-spacing: -35px;
  font-size:180px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:rgba(22, 160, 133, 1);
  font-family:arial
}
```

```html
<p class="blend blend-style" blend-mode="difference" data="BlendMe!"></p>
```

The goal here in the JS, is to split the word and set style property for blending mode on each letter separately. please don't forget to check as answered

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mostafa, this is fantastic! Im having a next challenge now with changing the text with animation. Wonder if there is a way for js to grab the text that was added with css @keyframes. I'll post another question with bits of your code, if you can help with that too that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate this by using an `rgba` color for the font

```css
.blended-text {
  color: rgba(0, 50, 0, 70%);
  font: 21em sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -70px;
}
```

```html
<span class="blended-text">Blend</span>
```